# Logistic regression with ordinal explanatory variable

Tags: sas, bioinformatics

I have a set of data where I would like to do logistic regression modeling the odds of a binary outcome variable (Therapy), with Stage as an ordinal explanatory variable (0,1,2,3,4). Hba1c is a continuous variable.

Is my class statement correct?

How do I get it to calculate the odds ratios for each level of the ordinal variable?

```
PROC LOGISTIC data=new;
class EyeID Therapy (ref ="0") Stage (param = ordinal) Gender (ref="M") Ethnicity (ref="C")/ param = ref;
model Therapy = Stage Gender age A1c Ethnicity;
oddsratio Stage;
run;
```

This is the Output:

```
Odds Ratio Estimates and Wald Confidence Intervals
Odds Ratio  Estimate    95% Confidence Limits
Stage 1 vs 0    0.873   0.547   1.394
Stage 2 vs 0    2.434   0.895   6.620
Stage 3 vs 0    0.915   0.431   1.941
Stage 4 vs 0    0.356   0.132   0.961
Stage 2 vs 1    2.788   0.980   7.935
Stage 3 vs 1    1.048   0.465   2.360
Stage 4 vs 1    0.408   0.144   1.156
Stage 3 vs 2    0.376   0.113   1.249
Stage 4 vs 2    0.146   0.038   0.567
Stage 4 vs 3    0.389   0.117   1.288
```

If I am reporting Stage as an ordinal variable, then is it correct that I create a table like this?

```
Stage 1 vs 0    0.873   0.547   1.394
Stage 2 vs 1    2.788   0.98    7.935
Stage 3 vs 2    0.376   0.113   1.249
Stage 4 vs 3    0.389   0.117   1.288
```

I should not report it like this, correct? This is if stage was categorical?

```
Stage 1 vs 0    0.873   0.547   1.394
Stage 2 vs 0    2.434   0.895   6.62
Stage 3 vs 0    0.915   0.431   1.941
Stage 4 vs 0    0.356   0.132   0.961
```

Comment: Ordinal models cumulative probability, not in comparison to a reference level. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Reeza I have updated the post. Am I interpreting the output correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need `Therapy` on the class statement.

Without sample data, I cannot test this, but my first pass would have been to write it like this.

```
proc logistic data=test;
class PVDStage (param = ordinal);
model Therapy(ref = '0') = PVDStage hba1c;
ODDSRATIO PVDStage;
run;
```

If you can provide some sample data, I will amend my answer to ensure it works.

Comment: ref='0' should be event='0' and in fact will lead to unexpected results. The default will be used and SAS doesn't through an error, which seems strange .

Comment: I have never had a problem with that syntax giving a problem. Do you have a SAS Note or Doc link that discusses it?

Comment: No, But if you run the following code  you'll see the a note in the log that shows this is an issue.  Proc logistic data=sashelp.heart; class CholStatus/ Param=ordinal; model status(ref='Dead') = AgeAtStart CholStatus; run;

Comment: Actually never mind. I mixed up reference level and event definition which are opposite in a binary outcome.

Comment: @DomPazz, I have updated my original post. Am I interpreting the output correctly?